# JS file not triggering if I include another JSP file inside JSP file

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a main jsp file, inside of that JSP file, I have invoke a JS file and included another JSP file called login.jsp.

Before adding the include for login.jsp the functions of my JS file can be called. After adding the login.jsp it is no longer working.

I tested invoking the JS file inside the login.jsp, it is working that way. The thing is, I cannot do that because many JSP pages will include login.jsp and I don't need to call each and every JS file that uses the login.jsp.

Here is the code:

this is my main jsp file:

```
<html>
<head>
.. some scriplets with no error ...
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/pcLotsFrontProcessMaterialRegistration.js" ></SCRIPT>
.. other js files that is included this way ..
</head>
<body>
<div id="login_holder" align="center">
<jsp:include flush="true" page="../admin/login.jsp"></jsp:include>
</div>
... some codes ....

</body></html>
```

and my login.jsp is this :

```
<div id="login-box">
<table id="login-box-table">
... table contents ...
</table>
</div>
<script>
... functions ...
</script>
```

Is there something wrong with this format?

Please don't mind the scriplets and all I intend to modify them some other time, I just need to make this work first.

Thank you very much. :D

Comment: Have you reviewed the actual source code the browser receives from your code? Is the include path correct (that the browser sees)?

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to tell what's going on since you chose to omit the javascript, however it seems highly likely that something in the javascript in login.jsp is conflicting with the javascript in the 'main' jsp.

I suggest using a javascript console and debugger (like the Developer Tools in Chrome or FireFox) to find the problem.

By the way, this not a very good way to structure things, and is particularly prone to this type of problem.

First of all, you shouldn't have your javascript in your jsp pages - it should be in external .js files, and it should be name-spaced to avoid conflicts (I suggest reading Doug Crockford's 'Javascript - The Good Parts').

Second, there are much better ways to compose pages - for instance, take a look at the Apache Tiles project.

Answer (score -1):

How about using [JSP Scriptlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html) @include
like

```
<%@include file="../admin/login.jsp" %>
```

if your page is static page.